# Websphere portal. How to forward on target page?

Tags: websphere, target, portal, forward

I am using websphere portal 7.0. 
I want when I am logged in and trying to forward on public url like host:port/wps/portal/thomething portal forward me to host:port/wps/myportal/thomething, just rewrite portal on myportal. Now portal forward me on Home page. Maybe there is some setting or some portal filter that let to do this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved problem myself.

https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM27451

Just added to portal web.xml

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>Home Substitution Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.ibm.wps.engine.ServletSubstitutionFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
```